# Interactive plotting in spyder using pyvista widgets

Tags: plot, widget, spyder, interactive, pyvista

I need help regarding interactive plotting in spyder using pyvista (widgets??).  I checked the example files in pyvista site. When I run the example codes, all I get is static plots. I found a similar post here by Dr Thomas but I need a full code that generates a working interactive plot.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
p = pv.Plotter(notebook=False, window_size=(600,400))